# Basic definition of correlation of $X,Y$ when $X$ or $Y=0$

Tags: probability

The wikipedia definition of correlation is
$$
\rho_{X,Y} = \frac{\mathrm{Cov(X,Y)}}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}
$$
where $X,Y$ are random variables with standard deviations $\sigma_X, \sigma_Y$ respectively.
Of course this is nonsense if $X=0$ almost surely. Just to make sure, we define $\rho_{X,Y} =0$ in this case, correct? Or is there a broader definition of $\rho_{X,Y}$ which does not involve division by $\sigma_X$?

Comment: An argument for $\rho_{X,Y} =0$ if either $X$ or $Y$ are almost surely constant is that in such a case you can say $X$ and $Y$ are almost surely independent and it is convenient to be able to have independence implying zero correlation.  It is not a strong argument, as it merely extends "independent with finite positive variances" to "independent with finite non-negative variances" implying zero correlation; it still does not cover the case of an infinite or undefined variance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only encountered the correlation between non-degenerate random variables. The definition i'm aware of:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be real non-degenerate random variables from $\mathcal{L}^2(P)$. Then the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ are defined to be
>   $$
> \rho(X,Y)=\frac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)}}.
> $$

Note that $X$ is degenerate if and only if $\mathrm{Var}(X)=0$. I suppose the important property of the correlation is the following:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-degenerate random variables from $\mathcal{L}^2(P)$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\rho(X,Y)\in\{-1,1\}$,
> 2. There exists $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$ such that $Y=\alpha+\beta X$ a.s.

By allowing degenerate random variables into the definition with $\rho=0$, the above result is no longer true. If $X=c_1$ and $Y=c_2$ a.s. then $Y=\alpha+\beta X$ a.s. with $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=\frac{c_2}{c_1}$. I would probably just stick with the definition for non-degenerate variables.